# Objective-C, I'm having some problems with arrays and dictionaries atrting at zero or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm using a dictionary and an array to store the section title for a table view, along with the number of rows in each. I'm adding to the array and the dictionary in a loop of the records from my database in mu populateDataSource method.

I've got two dates from three records in my database. 2010-11-05 and 2010-11-07

I'm not sure if its because the table view events need to start at zero and the dictionary / array start at one ?

Or maybe my sectionTitles addObject, is added values each time, rather than adding unique dates. If so how i can search or only allow unique values ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... what's the expected result?

Comment: It's easier to read if you paste your code and your log results, rather than attaching a screen shot.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays have a starting index of 0, but dictionaries don't essentially work that way.  What is the purpose of the dictionary in this case? To get an object from the dictionary you give it a key.  If you're going through a loop and not getting the expected result, maybe the dictionary isn't getting the key that it should be.